# UIAccessibilityScrollDirection won't scroll good

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, uiaccessibility

I'm using [MBXPageViewController](https://github.com/Moblox/MBXPageViewController) as a `UIPageViewController`.
I'm trying to make the app more accessible with the `UIAccessibilityScrollDirection` method.

This works almost fine, but has a couple of issues:

- The scrollDirection makes 2 steps to the right at first. I've logged it and give a currentIndex from 0 -> 2.
- The scrollDirection won't go back to the first `childViewController`, the currentIndex 0. Voice-over tells there is no object left.

Here is how the accessibilityScroll method look like.

The `setPageControllerForIndex:(NSInteger)index direction:(UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection)direction currentMBXViewController:(id)weakSelf destionation:(NSInteger)destination` method is described [here](https://github.com/Moblox/MBXPageViewController/blob/master/MBXPageController/MBXPageViewController/MBXPageViewController.m#L256)

```
    -(BOOL)accessibilityScroll:(UIAccessibilityScrollDirection)direction {

    __weak __typeof(&*self)weakSelf = self;
    NSInteger tempIndex = _currentPageIndex;

    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)tempIndex);

    if (direction == UIAccessibilityScrollDirectionRight) {
        //Previous Page
        if (direction < tempIndex) {
            NSLog(@"links");
            for (int i = (int)tempIndex-1; i >= direction; i--) {
                [self setPageControllerForIndex:i direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse currentMBXViewController:weakSelf destionation:direction];
                NSLog(@"%d", i);
            }
            NSLog(@"%ld", direction);
            UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityPageScrolledNotification, @"links");
        }

    } else if (direction == UIAccessibilityScrollDirectionLeft) {
        //Next Page
        if (direction > tempIndex) {
            NSLog(@"rechts");
            for (int i = (int)tempIndex+1; i <= direction; i++) {
                [self setPageControllerForIndex:i direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward currentMBXViewController:weakSelf destionation:direction];
                NSLog(@"%d", i);
            }
            NSLog(@"%ld", direction);
            UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityPageScrolledNotification, @"rechts");
        }
    }
    UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityPageScrolledNotification, nil);
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `direction` in the for loops?

Comment: To calculate the next page direction from the tempIndex.

Comment: The direction has the numerical values 1, 2, 3, 4 (right, left, up, down). I don't think that using that value in the condition of the for loop is what you want.

Comment: So you mean I shouldn't compare the `direction` value with the tempIndex? I'm still a beginner with this.

Comment: Found the solution! Thanks for the advice @DavidRönnqvist